# ruby explicit method return types

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm learning ruby (have a java/groovy background) and it looks like when writing methods, the method signature is

```
def method_name
    # do something
end
```

With ruby's dynamic nature, I understand why the return type is not explicitly declared. But let's say I have a method called `get_name`. As a caller of the code, I may not be sure if it returns a String or some custom Name type. Is there a way to explicitly declare the return type? And (if it is possible) is this really ever done in ruby to make it clear what the return value is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 2019: still no static typing or type annotations built into ruby, but we now have 3rd party type checkers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132394/125816) for more details.

---

Java performs static type checks. It ensures at compile time that all type requirements are met. Ruby is more dynamic, it doesn't do compile time checks and its type system is often referred to as "duck typing". That is, "If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck".

If a method expects an object that responds to certain messages (has certain methods), then it doesn't care about actual type of the object as long it conforms to the protocol. If this is backed up by good test suite, then it's (arguably) a better way, because it allows for faster prototyping and reduced visual clutter. Less visual clutter - code is more expressive and understandable. Benefits of that are obvious. :)

Comment: Well, I read all my Ruby knowledge from a book and a lot of error filled code I wrote. No programer can say everything they said here didn't come from a book. Heck, some of the highest voted answers are documentation and standards quotes.

Comment: "The object-oriented programming languages Smalltalk, Ruby, Python, and Self are all "strongly typed" in the sense that typing errors are prevented at runtime and they do little implicit type conversion, but these languages make no use of static type checking: the compiler does not check or enforce type constraint rules. The term duck typing is now used to describe the dynamic typing paradigm used by the languages in this group." — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing Also be careful about arguing better ways in type systems, it's a minefield.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: that's why I put "arguably" in there, to protect my arse :)

Comment: @MichaelKohl: thanks for the link, reworded that first sentence :)

Comment: "If a method expects an object that responds to certain messages (has certain methods), then it doesn't care about actual type of the object as long it conforms to the protocol." – The protocol *is* the actual type of the object.

Comment: Thanks. I understand duck typing from groovy. This was just more a question if it was possible so users of the method could easily determine the return type if needed without looking inside the method but it looks like the answer is no.

Comment: @JeffStorey: yes, there are no type annotations in ruby. Except those that you put in the documentation comments (some editors and IDEs show pretty tooltips).

Comment: What a miserable limitation. I wonder how people get used to this language.

Answer (score 5):

In 2019 Stripe released their type-checker for ruby, [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/). It is now possible to specify method signatures. Can look like this:

```
  sig {returns(String)}
  def name
    "Sergio"
  end
```

If you, for example, make a mistake with types, you'll get interesting errors.

Code:

```
  sig {returns(Integer)}
  def name
    "Sergio"
  end
```

Errors:

```
editor.rb:12: Returning value that does not conform to method result type https://srb.help/7005
    12 |    "Sergio"
            ^^^^^^^^
  Expected Integer
    editor.rb:11: Method name has return type Integer
    11 |  def name
          ^^^^^^^^
  Got String("Sergio") originating from:
    editor.rb:12:
    12 |    "Sergio"
            ^^^^^^^^
Errors: 1
```

You can play with the checker in the [online playground](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20A%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns(Integer)%7D%0A%20%20def%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%22Sergio%22%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Adef%20main%0A%20%20A.new.name%20%20%23%20error%3A%20Type%20mismatch!%0Aend).

Comment: Should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I find that the comment annotations provided by RubyMine / IntelliJ to be very helpful for this.   For example:

```
# @param [String] time_zone_offset_string eg. +10:00
# @return [Array] An array containing sign, hours and minutes
def self.parse_timezone_string(time_zone_offset_string)
  ... parse the timezone string ...
  return [sign, hours, minutes]
end
```

These annotations don't seem to be feature of [RDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc/Markup.html) - it would be great if they were.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is this: It is imposible and will never become posible. And it will never be used.

Here's the long answer: Ruby doesn't operate on types. Ruby operates on the generic object. Everything, at some point, is just a `BasicObject`. Ruby uses Duck Typeing, which has the core principle

> If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, the interpreter is happy to treat it as a duck.

You can check class with `Object#class` (returns class of an object) and `Object#is_a?(klass)`, but it is strongly discouraged by the community. Just think of it logically, read source code, and use documentation.

Comment: Never say never, see my other answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is impossible for ruby to define type of the return value of a method. But you can use method such as is_a? or class to check type.